# Kubuntu 18.04 - Touchpad recognized as mouse - Multitouch gestures not working

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch

I'm having a problem with my laptop, as the title says:
The trackpad is being recognized as a mouse, so I don't have multitouch gestures, other than scrolling.

I can't switch apps with gestures, I can't change trackbar specific configurations, because, according to the System Settings panel, I've got a mouse, and not a trackpad.

I had this same problem in Linux Mint and Ubuntu Mate 18.04, so I believe that it's not a distro-specific problem.

I've tried following other guides to make the multitouch gestures work, but most are for previous kernel versions and are focused on just making the touchpad work, AFAIK.

- My laptop is a Lenovo V330-15IKB.
- My kernel version is 5.3.0-26.generic
- running dmseg | grep elan I've got no results, and running:

```bsh
dmesg | grep i2c         
[    2.224353] i2c /dev entries driver
[    4.969912] i2c_hid i2c-AUI1657:00: i2c-AUI1657:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.969924] i2c_hid i2c-AUI1657:00: i2c-AUI1657:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.218914] input: AUI1657:00 044E:121E Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-5/i2c-AUI1657:00/0018:044E:121E.0001/input/input7
[    5.219023] input: AUI1657:00 044E:121E Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-5/i2c-AUI1657:00/0018:044E:121E.0001/input/input8
[    5.219075] input: AUI1657:00 044E:121E as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-5/i2c-AUI1657:00/0018:044E:121E.0001/input/input9
[    5.219139] hid-generic 0018:044E:121E.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [AUI1657:00 044E:121E] on i2c-AUI1657:00
```

- and running

```bsh
  sudo acpidump | grep -C3 ELAN
  E730: 4E 41 32 42 34 31 00 5F 48 49 44 A1 10 70 0D 53  NA2B41._HID..p.S
  E740: 59 4E 41 32 42 34 32 00 5F 48 49 44 A1 4E 07 A0  YNA2B42._HID.N..
  E750: 34 93 61 0A 02 A0 1D 91 93 60 0A 04 91 93 60 0A  4.a......`....`.
  E760: 02 93 60 00 70 0D 45 4C 41 4E 30 36 31 37 00 5F  ..`.p.ELAN0617._
  E770: 48 49 44 A1 10 70 0D 45 4C 41 4E 30 36 31 38 00  HID..p.ELAN0618.
  E780: 5F 48 49 44 A1 46 04 A0 32 93 61 0A 04 A0 1C 91  _HID.F..2.a.....
  E790: 93 60 0A 04 91 93 60 0A 02 93 60 00 70 0D 41 55  .`....`...`.p.AU
  E7A0: 49 31 36 35 36 00 5F 48 49 44 A1 0F 70 0D 41 55  I1656._HID..p.AU
```

I come from windows, and over there, I had this working really well. Could someone give me hand to make this work?. Thanks!